# Macro that is not executed at the start or the end of the page

Tags: macros, page-breaking

I need to define a macro (let's call it `\separator`) that it is not executed if it is the first or the last to be typeset on the page.

Consider the following mwe:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}

\newcommand{\separator}{\par\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\par}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\separator

Some more text.

And more.

The next \verb|\separator| (i.e., rule) should not be typeset.

\separator

\newpage

\separator

Now, we are on page \thepage. The previous \verb|\separator| (i.e., rule) should not have been typeset.

\end{document}
```

How should I modify the definition of `\separator` in order to achieve the desired result?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186330/1090

Comment: At the top of a page, `\pagegoal=\maxdimen` (which can be very annoying, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669361/problem-with-pagegoal)